# Passing Data from VC to VC and Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameter-passing

I have a levelViewController:

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


double delayTimeInSeconds = 2;
dispatch_time_t popTimeDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTimeInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTimeDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed after delay


    GameViewController *level1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameViewController"];

    level1.CARDS_PER_ROW = 6;
    level1.gameModel.NUMBER_OF_PAIRS = 3;

    [self presentViewController:level1 animated:NO completion:nil];


});//code to be executed after delay end

}
```

ok, he presents now the GameViewController with level1. The CARDS_PER_ROW is declared in GameViewController.h

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GameModel.h"


@interface GameViewController : UIViewController  

@property (nonatomic) GameModel *gameModel;

@property (nonatomic) int CARDS_PER_ROW;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger newGame;

@end
```

.m

in my ViewDidLoad i have

```
self.gameModel = [[GameModel alloc] initWithNewGame:self.newGame];
```

And for my GameViewController i have my GameModel:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GameModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int NUMBER_OF_PAIRS;

-(id) initWithNewGame: (NSInteger)newGame;

@end
```

.m

```
-(NSMutableArray *) createNewDeck {
NSMutableArray *cardDeck = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < _NUMBER_OF_PAIRS; i++) {
    [cardDeck addObject:[[CardModel alloc] initWithValue:i]];
    [cardDeck addObject:[[CardModel alloc] initWithValue:i]];
}

return cardDeck;
}
```

Ok. My Problem is:

I CAN passing CARDS_PER_ROW. If i define NUMBER_OF_PAIRS ( #define NUMBER_OF_PAIRS = x; ) it works. But i CANT passing my NUMBER_OF_PAIRS data, and i don't know why. The Screen is empty with this Code I've posted.

Comment: That's not how you use preprocessor `#define`.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. i don't want to use #define because its static, and i want to generate it through passing the NUMBER_OF_PAIRS data

Comment: Two things to note... 1) You could use the much easier `- performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` & 2) Use an exception breakpoint to _verify_ that `gameModel` is not `nil` upon assignment (which is probably true due to the fact that the view of a controller is loaded the first time that is accessed)

Comment: how you are assigning value NUMBER_OF_PAIRS

Comment: @Alladinian: I tryed : level1.gameModel = [[GameModel alloc] initWithNewGame:level1.newGame]; Isn't that enough?                 Ritu: Don't know what you mean exactly? I write a Value in my levelViewController, and that Value i want to pass to my GameModel to initialize the pairs with this value

Comment: @Sausagesalad I wouldn't know if that is enough... it depends... the initialization in `-viewDidLoad:` would re-initialize it anyways...

Comment: ive deleted the initialization in viewdidload shortly for testing it in levelviewcontroller but it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `gameModel` is `nil` at that point. The fact that you have instantiated a controller doesn't mean that its `view` is also loaded, the view will be lazy-loaded at first access. So, what you can do is to move the `gameModel` initializer to the controller's initializer (`-initWithCoder` in case of a nib/storyboard instantiation)

Comment: Can you Write me your Solution? Im not getting it, what to do... Ive tryed so much in the last three days. The Gamemodel initializer is now in My gameviewcontroller, so you mean i have to put the initializer to my levelviewcontroller and the initwithcoder in gameviewcontroller?

Comment: What I mean is that you can initialize `gameModel` inside `initWithCoder:` on your `GameViewController` (the one you instantiate from the storyboard). Then put a breakpoint on its `-viewDidLoad` to verify that is properly initialized and its `NUMBER_OF_PAIRS` is `3`. I hope that this makes sense... PS: Where do you set `self.newGame` ?

Comment: everything I've tried doesn't working. the only code thats works is with #define NUMBER_OF_PAIRS 6. im disappointed....